# Jetpack Compose make nested subcomposables have matching widths

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have multiple composables (`Text`) forming a visual column and I would like to make them have the same width (though not necessarily for themselves, but to make column 2 aligned)
The problem is I can't just move the column dimension inside (column of rows -> row of columns) because there are other elements involved (red is set to consume all available space and yellow takes up the whole width):
[image: simplified goal layout]

I've looked into `SubcomposeLayout` but I can't see how I could fit the whole thing inside and measure the texts.

My current layout looks like this:

**Column** (parent layout)

- Row
- - Text 1
- - ...
- Column with foreach x in 2,3,4
- - Column
- - - Row
- - - - Text x

I only have to work with a limited and static set of texts so worst case, I will add all of them into each field and make all but one invisible, but even a solution where I do this just once, measure it and only apply `defaultMinSize` to all of them would be nice.

Edit: I don't think this is achievable by simple weights
[image: Desired layout]

Comment: Have you tried working with the .weight() modifier?

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the **`weight`** modifier:

```
Column(

) {

    Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
       Text("Text1",Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, Black))
       Text("Text2",Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, Black))
       Text("Text3",Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, Black))
    }
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(20.dp).background(Yellow))
    }
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
        Text("Text1",Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, Black))
        Text("Text2",Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, Black))
        Text("Text3",Modifier.weight(1f).border(1.dp, Black))
    }
}
```

[image]